# Cumprod over mutliple sub-segments

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe which is a merge of multiples of entities. Each row represents an entry in one of the entities.

Something like

```
Entity_key entry_key value
1          1         2
1          2         5
1          3         0.5
2          1         10
2          2         5
```

I'd like to do a cum-prod on the values, so that id would produce something like

```
Entity_key entry_key value  cumprod
1          1         2        2
1          2         5        10
1          3         0.5       5
2          1         10       10
2          2         5        50
```

I could, of course, just iterate through entity keys and do it entity-by-entity, but I'm wondering whether there's a more efficient way of doing it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a helper column and groupby with cumprod:

```
df['cumprod_'] = df.groupby(df['entry_key'].eq(1).cumsum())['value'].cumprod()
```

---

```
print(df)

   Entity_key  entry_key  value  cumprod_
0           1          1    2.0       2.0
1           1          2    5.0      10.0
2           1          3    0.5       5.0
3           2          1   10.0      10.0
4           2          2    5.0      50.0
```

*What does the helper column do?*

It checks for entry_key = 1 and then cumulatively sums to create distinct groups:

```
print(df['entry_key'].eq(1).cumsum())

0    1
1    1
2    1
3    2
4    2
Name: entry_key, dtype: int32
```

Comment: just as a note, your solution works _only_ if the DF is sorted by the entity_key and then entry_key. Anything that messes up the sort before then will throw it out (and make it hard to find why it's out)